# Django: Can't filter spanned relationships

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a few models and I'd like to filter out specific fields, but I keep getting the error: Cannot resolve keyword 'Unique' into field. Choices are:Parent, id, unique. Here are my model and my filter lookup:

```
    #models

class Parent(models.Model):
    parent_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    objects = models.Manager()


class Unique(models.Model):
    unique_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objects = models.Manager()


class Name(models.Model):
    name_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    unique = models.ForeignKey(Unique, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objects = models.Manager()


class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    name = models.ForeignKey(Name, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    objects = models.Manager()
```

Here is the query I've been trying:

```
if Parent.objects.filter(parent_name__iexact = new_parent.parent_name,
        unique__unique_name__iexact = new_unique.unique_name, 
        unique__name__name_name__iexact = new_name.name_name, 
        unique__name__item__item_name__iexact = new_item.item_name).exists():
```

I want to ensure that certain models spanning through a ForeignKey relationship exist within the database. The New_ variables are form inputs.

edit: I got the code to work, I must have messed up something pretty small. The current code works, and I'll be using PEP8 from now on to spot mistakes better, thanks :)

Comment: I find it a bit weird that your fields start with an Uppercase, typically fields are lowercase.

Comment: For the filtering, there is there can be multiple `Unique`s for a parent, so in that case by default the reverse is `unique_set`.

Comment: Its not related with the problem, but your code looks so strange, you should follow the python style guide: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: You also dont need to chain filters like that, you can have just one `.filter()` and separate the filters by commas.

Comment: It would also be less confusing for yourself and everyone if you didn't use the same word for the model and the field, e.g. Parent.Parent. Use name/title/description/identifier or something, since it's a string.

Comment: I would advice you to first normalize your model, and make it less confusing by using proper naming. Yes, this will not solve the underlying problem, but right now, it only costs an awful lot of braincycles, simply to understand the modeling. You also do not need to add `object` managers yourself: Django does this as long as those are the default ones.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've done unique_set but it still gives me a similar error, I've also already normalized my model properly. There's a ton more models that are a part of Unique, as well as Item. And Pycharm gives me problems if I don't include the object manager, so I decided to include them.

Comment: Well my guess is that the problem is with the `unique__name__Name_Name__iexact`, since your `Unique` reference is with an uppercase, and has no `name`, but a `name_set`, etc. So it is a similar problem, yes.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The problem is that the second filter `unique__Unique_Name__iexact` doesn't go through. The lowercase can be seen in the documentation and refers to [reverse relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/)

Comment: @Martin: well by default a foreign key has a reverse that is named `classname_set`, since this is a one-to-many relation. So it should be `unique_set`. Funny enough it is on exactly the page you cited: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's in the case that the variable is assigned a model instance of the parent class. In which case, _set is used to get a reverse relationship and directly access the model field. In the case of a lookup, which is what I'm doing, you don't need _set, you simply include the names of the classes https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrite your code using the PEP8 recommendation and Django good practices, it should looks like this:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    parent = models.CharField(max_length=30)


class Unique(models.Model):
    unique = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='uniques')


class Name(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    unique = models.ForeignKey(Unique, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='names')


class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    name = models.ForeignKey(Name, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items')


has_parents = Parent.objects.filter(
    parent__iexact=new_parent.parent,
    uniques__unique__iexact=new_unique.unique,
    uniques__names__name__iexact=new_name.name,
    uniques__names__items__item_name__iexact=new_item.item_name
).exists()

if has_parents:
    do_something()
```

I will even recommend you to change that fields that was equals with the model name.

As you can see, its so much more readable that your code, as Pythonists we are really annoying with it.